# Javascript setTimeout is sometimes not triggered in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, angular, android-webview

We have a small Android app which mainly consists of a WebView. In this WebView, we load an Angular 2 App (Angular 2.4) which regularily polls an API. To trigger the polling regularily, we use a recursive call:

```
private xxx() {
  console.log("Beginning of xxx");
  ...
  http.get(url).then( => {
    console.log("Before setTimeout");
    setTimeout(() => xxx(), 300);
  });
}
```

Polling usually works well, however, after some time (~ 1-2 min), polling stops. From our logging, we can see that the timeout is set (second log line above), but the callback is not called.

Things we have tried/learned so far:

- Viewing the app in Chrome on the same device does not reproduce the issue
- Remote debugging via Chrome development tools prevents the issue
- A touch event makes the app recommence the polling

Android version 6.0
API level: 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by updating  system.android.WebView from version 46.0.2490.76 to 58.0.3029.83.